# I/O error reading PNG header

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm becaming crazy to understand what i wrong.. 
If i use this istruction:

```
BufferedImage overlay = ImageIO.read(new File("/temp/approved.png"));
```

the image have transparency and the header of the file is:

```
‰PNG

IHDR....
```

**i get this exception:**

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading PNG header!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at test.image.UtilImage.getImagesOverlay(UtilImage.java:40)
.....
**Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Bad length for IHDR chunk!**
```

I'm using java jdk 1.8.0_40
Someone know why i have this issue.

Thanks

Update:
I understand that was a library in my project [mmsc_bmp](http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/bmp/index.html)
.... Thanks to everybody for the help

Comment: Please provide original file, otherwise it is impossible to say. @AndreyTaptunov this is not necessarily a dup, there a problem was with CgBI header. There is no mentioning of it in this question.

Comment: Open you image with a text/hex editor see if the first 16 bytes are 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A  00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52. If not, it doesn't conform to PNG spec especially the 9-12 bytes should be 00 00 00 0D, which is decimal 13 and is a fixed value for all PNG IHDR chunk.

Comment: Thaks ,about the first 16 byte the png have the same bytes.. and how i had wrote.. the problem was a library.. without all things works as expect

Comment: More detail: The binary generated from [mmscomputing](http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/index.html) (mmsc, which @zanny mentioned) has its own implementations of image readers for common types that appear to be limited and override the standard implementations.  For this reason, code that reads and writes images and used to work and hasn't changed will suddenly no longer work when this file is added to the classpath.